# World map different projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, cartography, display

I want to display something on a world map. 
I have these shapefiles http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php
I want my map to look something like this:

[image]

or

[image]

I am using QGis. Is that difficult to archive or do I 'simply' have to change the projection of the shapefile? I am lacking some theoretical knowledge and I do not know where to start searching...

Comment: Keep an eye on http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24725/is-the-mercator-projection-or-the-gall-peters-projection-of-the-world-more-accur/24738?s=1|0.6175#24738 ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since some of your desried projections may have problems with on-the-fly-reprojection, I suggest to create custom CRS for each projection, and save the shapefiles to that under a different name. Then create a new QGIS project, select the custom CRS as **project** CRS, and add the new shapefile layer.

Some CRS might fail if the north or south pole is included.

Comment: I wont be working on the projections. I just need them to create a map which I then want to print. No fancy operations needed...
Creating a custom CSR makes me a little bit nervous. How would I do that?

Comment: Eckert IV, Gall and Polyconic are already in QGIS. The first nameless example is World Mercator, and for Plate Caree you can take EPSG:4326. The second nameless, Goode Homolosine Interrupted, needs a custom CRS, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17263/is-it-possible-to-use-the-goode-homolosine-projection-in-qgis

Comment: The last missing could be Gall-Peters, or Equal Area Conical, with lat_ts at 45°. This needs a custom CRS, QGIS has only lat_ts at 30°.

Comment: Ah, thanks. So reprojection would change the display of the map. Its that simple? :)

Comment: Yes. Just try out the worldwide projections available in QGIS.

Comment: Bummer, the azimuth north equal areas raises an error... But the equal distance works. Weird

Comment: The North pole projections don't like Antarctica. You have to delete it before reprojecting.